# BeautifulSoup - modifying all links in a piece of HTML?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to be able to modify every single link in an HTML document. I know that I need to use the `SoupStrainer` but I'm not 100% positive on how to implement it. If someone could direct me to a good resource or provide a code example, it'd be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work? (I don't have a Python interpreter in front of me, unfortunately)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Blah blah blah <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
  a['href'] = a['href'].replace("google", "mysite")

result = str(soup)
```

Answer (score 32):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Blah blah blah <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    a['href'] = a['href'].replace("google", "mysite")
print str(soup)
```

This is Lusid's solution, but since he didn't have a Python interpreter in front of him, he wasn't able to test it and it had a few errors. I just wanted to post the working condition. Thank's  Lusid!

Comment: You probably want to check the crappy-HTML edge case where the a element you're testing doesn't have an href.

Comment: @Robert, yes you're right. I'll be sure to do so. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Evan, glad I was able to at least help you get there. My Python is a tad bit on the rusty side. :)

Comment: `soup.prettify()` is easier for human eyes than `str(soup)`.

Comment: Actually, that's a pretty common situation for named anchor tags:

    <a name='foo'></a>

Comment: @PeterRowell: `soup.findAll('a', href=True)` ensures that `a['href']` works

Answer (score 8):

I tried this and it worked, it's easier to avoid using regexp for matching each `'href'`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(htmltext)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    a['href'] = "mysite"
```

Check it out, on [bs4 docs](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#modifying-the-tree).