# Regex for href in a-element only

Tags: python, regex

I'd like only to replace the data of the href-attribute in an a-element. Can this be done with a regex?

**Example**

```
<a href="tel:8196887620" value="+18196887620" target="_blank">8196887620</a>
```

I imagine you'll have to make a regex for `<a ... >` then apply another regex for the `href` and then another to only grab the data between the `"`. Is that correct or is there a better way to do this? Maybe a library in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3005188

Comment: Use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: **-1** This has been asked a zillion time

Answer (score 2):

Using `BeautifulSoup` get 'anchor' tag `href=`

```
        import urllib
        from BeautifulSoup import *
        url = raw_input('Enter - ')
        html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        tags = soup('a')
        for tag in tags:
           print tag.get('href', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all. BeautifulSoup seems the way to go.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Blah blah blah <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p>')
for a in soup.findAll('a')
  a['href'] = a['href'].replace("google", "mysite")    
result = str(soup)
```

Source: [BeautifulSoup - modifying all links in a piece of HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459981/beautifulsoup-modifying-all-links-in-a-piece-of-html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with regexps efficiently, because it is a (nearly) type3 - language. HTML is type2.

Altough as quick-and-dirty solutions they can maybe work, but you will fast reach their limits. In your case, it is the point.

If you really want, a solution like this will maybe work:

```
/<a [^>]*href="([^"]*)"/
```

A better solution were if you googled a little bit for xslt processing. There are good xslt-processing tools even for the command line, they did it for you.