# How to change attribute value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

My "view" button has the following element:

```
<a href="../a/stutransDet.php?sid=23" style="text-decoration: none;  FONT-SIZE: 1.0em;  color:black" target="">View Grade</a>
```

I selected the "view" button like this

`view = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td1/div[5]/a")
a = view.get_attribute('href')   # www.abc.com/a/stutransDet.php?sid=23`

What I want is that I'll change the "href" of "view" so that when I click the "view" button, it will redirect to

```
 www.abc.com/a/stutransDet.php?sid=33
```

instead of

```
www.abc.com/a/stutransDet.php?sid=23
```

Is this possible? 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459981/beautifulsoup-modifying-all-links-in-a-piece-of-html) didn't work for me

Comment: Include in your code what did you try to do and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: what did you try so far???

Comment: @Giorgos I tried ".replace" method that didn't work. Can you provide how to do that? My pc got stuck (ubuntu 18.04 problem) so couldn't write the code.

Comment: Is it so difficult to provide the code with your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution to update `@href` value:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].href = "www.abc.com/id=12";', view)
```

Comment: @Nitesh , welcome. [Accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your issue