# How to strip this link to remove unwanted data (bs4)?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="full-news none">
     Demo: <a href="https://www.lolinez.com/?https://www.makemytrip.com" 
    rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a>
   <br/>
```

How can I remove this part from the href: `https://www.lolinez.com/?`, so that the final output becomes like this:

```
 <div class="full-news none">
         Demo: <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com" 
        rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a>
       <br/>
```

I have tried using the `decompose` function of beautiful soup, but it completely removes the entire tag, How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you expand your question and clarify why you can't just find&replace or another form of replace?

Comment: Why do manual find and replace buddy ? automating stuffs, thats the fun of python..i guess...

Comment: You can automate find&replace in python. If that's a suitable solution then you can use replace() https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/

Comment: that i know, but how to navigate inside this html structure, then do the needed, let me know if you know the solution to it

Comment: Without some more context on why you want to do that specifically (hence my original comment) its hard to say, but this may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459981/beautifulsoup-modifying-all-links-in-a-piece-of-html You can select only certain links to modify using normal bs4 techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** *Without additional context I would narrow down to following approaches*

###### Option#1

Replace your substring the `string` that you pass to `BeautifulSoup` constructor:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(YOUR_STRING.replace('https://www.lolinez.com/?',''), 'lxml')
```

###### Option#2

Replace the substring in your `soup` you can select all the `<a>` that contains `www.lolinez.com` and replace the value of its `href`:

```
for x in soup.select('a[href*="www.lolinez.com"]'):
    x['href'] = x['href'].replace('https://www.lolinez.com/?','')
```

##### Example

```
import bs4, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<a href="https://www.lolinez.com/?https://www.makemytrip.com" rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a>
<a href="https://www.makemytrip.com" rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a>
<a href="https://www.lolinez.com/?https://www.makemytrip.com" rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for x in soup.select('a[href*="www.lolinez.com"]'):
    x['href'] = x['href'].replace('https://www.lolinez.com/?','')
    
soup
```

##### Output

```
<html><body><a href="https://www.makemytrip.com" rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a><a href="https://www.makemytrip.com" rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a><a href="https://www.makemytrip.com" rel="external noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">https://www.makemytrip.com</a></body></html>
```